# Pandas dataframe how to add a columns based on rank in a dates vector

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a vector of dates

```
L = [Timestamp('2018-07-15 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2019-07-15 00:00:00')]
```

and a dataframe with a date column:

```
df = c1 c2 Date
     1. 2. 2018-07-13 16:00:00
     1. 7. 2018-07-15 16:00:00
     3. 7. 2018-07-15 16:50:00
     4. 7. 2018-07-15 19:50:00
     2. 2. 2018-07-16 16:00:00
     5. 1. 2020-10-10 16:00:00
     8. 4. 2018-06-13 16:00:00   
     5. 4. 2021-12-13 16:00:00
     2. 9. 2019-01-01 16:00:00
     2. 6. 2019-01-01 17:00:00
```

I want to add a column that is the rank in the dates vector, and delete rows from the same date (regardless of hour/minutes).
So I will have:

```
df = c1 c2 d.                  new
     1. 2. 2018-07-13 16:00:00  0
     1. 4. 2018-06-13 16:00:00  0
     2. 2. 2018-07-16 16:00:00  1
     5. 1. 2020-10-10 16:00:00  2
     8. 4. 2018-06-13 16:00:00  0
     5. 4. 2021-12-13 16:00:00  2
     2. 9. 2019-01-01 16:00:00  1
     2. 6. 2019-01-01 17:00:00. 1
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare 2 numpy arrays with broadcasting, for count `True`s use `sum`, last filter out matched dates without times with [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with invert mask by `~`:

```
L = [pd.Timestamp('2018-07-15 00:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('2019-07-15 00:00:00')]

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['new'] = (df['Date'].to_numpy()[:, None] > pd.to_datetime(L).to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)

df1 = df[~df['Date'].dt.normalize().isin(L)]
print (df1)
    c1   c2                Date  new
0  1.0  2.0 2018-07-13 16:00:00    0
4  2.0  2.0 2018-07-16 16:00:00    1
5  5.0  1.0 2020-10-10 16:00:00    2
6  8.0  4.0 2018-06-13 16:00:00    0
7  5.0  4.0 2021-12-13 16:00:00    2
8  2.0  9.0 2019-01-01 16:00:00    1
9  2.0  6.0 2019-01-01 17:00:00    1
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The rank is the rank of the time column in L. Please see the edit with the new example

Comment: @okuoub - Sorry, so there are added new rows? What is logic for rank?

Comment: this is the rank of the Date column value with relation to the dates provided by the L

Comment: @okuoub - so tested if higher like values in list? Answer was edited.

Comment: pls check latest edit I hope it is clear now. The rank is basically mean "if the date value was in L , what was his rank there"

Comment: I am sorry but pls the last and final edit. There might be multiple row from the same day. A row should be removed if it from the day of any of the dates in L - so has to be an exact match

Comment: @okuoub - answer was edited.